# How to use :cart_id to find the current cart by session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get totally confused when i read the book Agile web development with rails , Task D.

I know the current_cart method in the base class can find the target cart by session. However, i don't know where the sysbol :card_id is from.

When the lineItemController calls the current_cart method, what is the value of :cart_id?

What's more, I have already run the common "rails generate scaffold line_item product_id:integer cart_id integer". What is the relationship between these two kinds of cart_id?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
    def current_cart
       Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
       cart = Cart.create
       session[:cart_id] = cart.id
       cart
    end
end
```

Comment: `:card_id` is just a key; a symbol. Similar to a string. It's just a way to identify your `cart.id` in your session Hash later on.

Answer (score 1):

Initially value of `session[:cart_id]` will be nil so `Cart.find(session[:cart_id])` will throw error hence code of rescue block is get executed. it does three things

```
1. Create a new Cart
2. Save the id of newly created Cart in session
3. return the newly created cart
```

When same method is get called it will simply return the `Cart.find(session[:cart_id])`

Answer (score 1):

Cart has many line_items. There is a one to many relationship between carts and line_items.
So id of carts will be the foreign key in line_items i.e. cart_id.

:cart_id contains the value of cart_id.

And hence, In method current_cart, you are trying to find carts having id equals to cart_id.

And if the card with id = cart_id doesn't exists then it throws the error and in rescue block it creates new cart and save its id into session[:cart_id] and returns the cart.